# CSS gradients don't appear symmetrical?

Tags: css

I have this set up as an element's background:

```
div{
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #6f5a40 40%, #149f79 60%);
}
```

But the gradient seems to strongly favor the green color despite both colors being given equal space on the gradient function.  Is this simply a trick of our eyes, being able to distinguish green better than other colors, or is there something I can do programmatically to fix this?  Switching the order of the gradients doesn't seem to do anything: green appears to be favored over the brown.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xw6fqymu/

EDIT: I should also point out that this gradient is being overlaid on an image, where the effect is even more noticeable.  I don't imagine the image has much to do with this at all since reordering the colors with the image has about as much effect as without the image.

Comment: seems to be purely perceptual issue

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be a perceptual and not a programmatic issue.

Comment: I made [this fiddle which shows the gradient percentages are correct](http://jsfiddle.net/0r8sa98k/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a perceptual issue.

Here are two sample pictures I've created in a graphic editor. 
Both gradients are purely linear (0% to 100%).

[image: Grey-darkgreen-gradient]
[image: Black-blue-gradient]

As you probably notice, eye starts to perceives colors close to the desaturated edge very early.

---

What you may do is a non-symmetric distribution, e.g. `linear-gradient(to right, #6f5a40 48%, #149f79 70%);` — [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzyezvy0/).